# Xinetd Bind fails for check_mk serivce

Tags: check-mk

I am trying to start adding our Linux servers to our Check_MK monitoring by installing the agent.  I have installed Xinetd and the Check_MK_Agent RPM from my Check_MK server.  The Check_MK agent however does not seem to be running.

When I do a "status xinetd.service" I see a few errors which I feel are saying that it isn't starting

```
    xinetd[1533]: bind failed (Address already in use (errno = 98)). service = check_mk
    xinetd[1533]: Service check_mk failed to start and is deactivated.
```

I'm unsure what the cause of this is.  I thought maybe something else was on that port but a "netstat -antelup |grep -i 6556" doesn't only shows

```
    tcp6       0      0 :::6556                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          17995      -
```

which I'm not sure if that is specifically running and causing the issue or what is going on. My searches into the Bind Failed part have so far not turned up anything Check_MK related specifically and most of the answers I have found seem to me to be going off on tangents or are just going over my head.

Any help or insight that you could bring would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to resolve this issue ? I had similar issue with check_mk.

Port 6556 was already used by some other process. I verified my check_mk setup by changing port number in /etc/xinetd.d/check_mk and restarted xinetd.

It proved no issue with my agent installation as well as xinted and then I found the process that uses 6556 and killed it.

Output from my testing with different port.

tcp        0      0 :::**6559**                     :::*                        LISTEN      0          8283562   45970/**xinetd**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had two config files in

```
/etc/xinetd.d/check_mk and check_mk_agent
```

with the same settings so i deleted one.
Restarted the xinetd service and everything is fine.